# How do you make UITextField go into edit mode when UITextView row selected

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITextField subview within one of my UITableView rows. When I tap on a row (outside of the UITextField frame), I would like the UITextField to become editable (ie. make the numeric keypad appear) as if I had tapped within the UITextField frame.

I have seen some similar questions which suggested using becomeFirstResponder but this isn't working for me.

How would I do this? Should I be forwarding the touch events outside of the UITextField frame into the UITextField somehow?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  [self selectSection: indexPath.section];

  switch( indexPath.section )
  {      
    case SECTION_RATE:
      currentTextField = editRate;
      [editRate becomeFirstResponder];
      break;

    case SECTION_UNITS:
      currentTextField = editUnits;
      [editUnits becomeFirstResponder];
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath check the index path and

```
 tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 

if(indexpath.row == 0)
{
 [txtField1 becomeFirstResponder];
 //adjust table scroll for keyboard 
}
else if(indexpath.row == 1)
{
 [txtField2 becomeFirstResponder];
 //adjust table scroll for keyboard 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my posting above - I was doing something similar to what you have suggested. Just commented out the selectSection method call and it works.. so I must have a bug in my selectSection method (which is really just to keep track on what is selected and dismiss my UIPickerView that may be displayed). I will accept your answer as you have confirmed that I'm doing the "right" thing already.. I just need to find my bugs. :)